# How to disable recycler view item selection

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, material-design

```
movieListRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                        // true: consume touch event
                        // false: dispatch touch event
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

but once disabled I am not able to enable it back ,is there any way to make it work like toggle which will enable and disable RecyclerView

also **recyclerview.setEnabled(false)** is not working

Comment: do you mean whole RecyclerView ?

Comment: @TheFlash yes ,after click of button RecyclerView should be freezed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

Use **boolean** variable and setting default value to false and change value on button click.

```
boolean touch = false;

    movieListRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                            // true: consume touch event
                            // false: dispatch touch event
                            return touch;
                        }
                    });
```

and on your button click or whatever click change boolean value;

```
 onClick(){
 touch = !touch;
}
```

Comment: @swanandkeskar :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable click on whole items of recyclerview then add below lines in parent view of **row item**.

```
  android:clickable="false"
  android:focusable="false"
```